# What is the significance of Marriage as per Sanatana dharma?

Tags: gods, marriage, grihastha

Firstly would like to know the **Deeper significance of a Marriage**.

Few enlightened souls tell no need to marry(adopt sanyasa ashram) to achieve God but few others do tell Gruhastha ashrama is the one of the best(Shreshta) way to achieve the divine.

Could any one please share your thoughts on this and shed some light which is the path very near to the God and loved by him and listens to his devotees prayers.

Comment: Listen to your parents. One cannot take Sanyasa without his mother's (and later, his wife's) permission. If you can be in Gruhasthashrama without being attached (live like a guest even in your own home), then it is karma yoga. If you are in Sanyasa, then it is Karma Tyaga. In Kali Yuga, it is very hard to mentally renounce, even though physical renunciation can be done e.g. all fake samiyaars and gurus. So, it is better to be Karma yogi, than Karma tyagi. One will lead to God easily, other will lead to hell easily. Both paths are possible, but only first path is probable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **AykAshramyam tvacAryA: pratyakshavidhAnAt gArhasthasya** | (Apasthamba Sutram)
>
> Meaning - There is only one Ashramam and that is Grahastha dharma.
>   Thus, the only Ashramam advocated by the vedAs is the eternal
>   gArhastyAshramam and none other. This is the reason why all our seers
>   (cause for our gotrAs) like atri , vasishta ,agastya , bharadvAja ,etc
>   led a lifestyle of jaDa, maravuri, living with consort in the forest,
>   doing penance, performing daily rituals (nitya karmA) , upAsana
>   (worship) of agni , yagnyA and chanting of vedAs until their last
>   breath.
>
> It should be understood that there is no virtue that is superior to
>   "Daampatya-dharma’, the path of married life. Every one should follow
>   this advice of wisdom-Incarnate throughout their life time as wedlock
>   is the way to salvation. One can never experience the fruit of
>   creation without Wedlock. Male and Female species in creation are
>   complementary to each other. One can become whole and complete only
>   after Wedlock. Without Wedlock neither man nor woman can attain
>   fulfillment- they will remain incomplete.
>
> The cause of this universe and the basis for all existence  is the
>   penance of Brahman. The result of unswerving penance is knowledge
>   (vidya), gnyAnam , satyam (truth) , sukham (Happiness). This world,
>   created by, and resulting from unswerving penance, has these aspects
>   of form:  vidyArUpam , gnyAnarUpam , satyarUpam , sukharUpam . The
>   same is bestowed upon us by the vedAs. Vedas have provided a platform
>   for every soul (being in their respective states) to experience this
>   'Brahman'. ( the ultimate power)
>
> The main objective of all the Vedas is ‘garhastyashramam’ i.e,  family
>   life (dampatya). ‘**Brahmacharyam**’ is instrumental and the
>   **preliminary** practice for ‘garhastyashramam’. Brahmacharyam is the life of Veda adyayanam, enjoying all sorts of happiness, well being,
>   etc i.e. Shastric veda adyayanam is brahmacharyam. Brahmacharyam is
>   also known as ‘garhasyta sadhanam’ as it is preliminary and part of
>   the garhastyashramam referred to in the Vedas.  Brahmacharyam which is
>   the life of Veda adyayanam and Gayathri upasana is applicable for all,
>   irrespective of their sex and creed. The regulated  proper method  of 
>   mastering  Vedas  etc.,    helps  one lead  Dhampathya  life 
>   successfully.  This is applicable to woman also. Women are entitled to
>   all ceremonies like Upanayanam, etc.
>
> Mastering the Vedas as ordained is itself a Tapas (Penance). It must
>   be noted that Karma (or action) and Jnana (or knowledge) are not two
>   separate entities. Therefore there is no separate path for Jnanamarga.
>   There is only one path, and that is Vedamarga, the path of the Vedas.
>   Its culmination is in Dhampathya life. The Maharshi couple led the
>   Dhampathya life throughout their lives. Remaining in that Dhampathya,
>   one should desire good progeny, beget ideal children and bring them up
>   with great care. They are the true wealth for ‘the here’ and ‘the
>   hereafter.’  Immortals are fortunate enough to hear the lisping of
>   their children. In a sense, one can attain immortality, if, being of
>   good character, one is born as his/her own progeny. The Vedas state
>   this explicitly.
>
> When a man and a woman of pure conduct, bound by mutual love,
>   consummate their marriage, all elements like form, etc., get totally
>   absorbed in the fire of their union. This absorption creates an
>   intoxicating light radiating from them. When this intoxicating light
>   is also absorbed, Ananda, or Bliss arises and shines forth. The light
>   is absorbed in itself, and Ananda shines. From that, issues forth a
>   child, the sum total of all elements. The Maharishis advised- Always
>   live in the state of Vedic Dampatya.
>
> The Mahashakthi  who created  the whole universe,  laid down  the
>   vedic path  so  that all mankind could live happily enjoying all
>   comforts- temporal and spiritual. The Vedic  path  is  nothing  but 
>   the  life  lived  by  the  Maharshis:  the  eternal  dhampathya life 
>   enjoined  by  the  Vedas.
>
> **“uthishtatha maaswapta agni michadhvam bharataaha” (YV)**
>
> This means “ O Bharathiyas! Awake and yearn for fire”, Bha in Sanskrit
>   means light. One who worships light is a Bharateeya. That India is
>   called Bharat clearly conveys that all Indians were following the
>   Vedas and leading a life as prescribed by the Vedas. It extols all to
>   worship fire which is the primordial energy behind all creation
>
> Vedic path refers to the **three stages of a person**:
>
> The initial stage, which is Brahmacharya: the study and learning of
>   Vedas and Gayathri Upasana, and worship of Agni through oblations
>   twice a day.
>
> The next stage is the Grihastashrama (getting into marital life) and
>   offering oblations to Agni by performing  Agni upasana , Yagas , etc.
>   along with the life partner which are meant for the evolution of one’s
>   self in the spiritual realm.
>
> The final stage is offering one’s body after death to the Agni that
>   was worshipped.
>
> It should be understood that **vanaprastha** is the **continuation**
>   of **grahastha** stage after discharging the duties and retiring along
>   with the **wife** and continuing **agni** upasana, **penance**, and
>   **nitya** **karmas**.
>
> To lead a life as prescribed by the [Vedas](http://www.sridevinatha.org/vedic.php), here is the system to
>   be followed by one and all:
>
> 1. Initiation into Gayathri Upasana
> 2. Study of the Vedas or understanding the messages given in them.
> 3. Agni upasana as part of Gayathri Upasana and vedic study      (BRAHMACHARYA).
> 4. Getting into married life and continuing Agni Worship as a couple – Grahastha Dharma.
> 5. Offering one’s body in the fire worshipped by the couple (The concept behind the ritual followed for cremation in the present day)

Comment: I feel like these are various parts of whole human life. It does not contain much detail about marriage(My personal opinion though).

Comment: @RonakBhatt grahastha/dampatya are synonyms for marriage only...

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57958/discussion-on-answer-by-rakesh-joshi-what-is-the-significance-of-marriage-as-per).