# Does hinduism also suggest shedding of karma and renunciation?

Tags: moksha, dharma-shastras

I know about 4 ashram and 4 purusharth but does it somewhere suggest that we should only focus on moksha (as in jainism) and not on purusharth and ashram system.

Comment: You can go through related answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18076/7853

Comment: The ultimate goal is Moksha itself through Dharma ,Artha & Kaama. Ved-Vyasa said with loud voice follow your dharma , by which you will get Artha & Kaama and ultimately Moksha.Its a step-by-step process for Gruhastha's.For Brahmachari's & sanyasis the path is different.

Comment: Actual Karma is done by mind, not physicality. Until quintessence of mind, you can't shed your Karma. Not walking but having desires of walking is Karma, but walking without desires of walking is not Karma. Also note that, what is desire here changes according to the system. Dedirelessness according to Advait Philosophy is indwelling in supreme consciousness, In Buddhism - no desire etc

Answer (score 7):

> but does it somewhere suggest that we should **only focus on moksha** (as
>   in jainism) and not on purusharth and ashram system.

No, it does not.

One can focus wholeheartedly on moksha once he has grown sufficiently old & when he has already fulfilled all his duties first.

**When one can fully focus on  liberation?**

> Manu Smriti 6.2. When a householder **sees his (skin) wrinkled, and
>   (his hair) white, and. the sons of his sons, then he may resort to the
>   forest.**

**What happens if someone applies himself fully for liberation without performing his preliminary duties first?**

> Manu Smriti 6.36. Having studied the Vedas in accordance with the
>   rule, having begat sons according to the sacred law, and having
>   offered sacrifices according to his ability, **he may direct his mind
>   to (the attainment of) final liberation**
>
> Manu Smriti 6.37. A twice-born man **who seeks final liberation,
>   without having studied the Vedas, without having begotten sons, and
>   without having offered sacrifices, sinks downwards**

Also, one who seeks moksha for oneself without clearing the three debts (debts to gods, sages and ancestors) first sinks to hell as said in the following verse:

> 6.35. When he has paid the three debts, let him apply his mind to (the attainment of) final liberation; **he who seeks it without having paid
>   (his debts) sinks downwards.**

However, in whatever ashrama one lives in Hinduism always emphasizes on collecting spiritual merit because:

> 4.239. **For in the next world** neither father, nor mother, nor wife, nor sons, nor relations stay to be his companions; **spiritual merit alone
>   remains (with him).**

Note- All verses are from Manu Smriti.

Comment: Nice one again. So it seems that there is no moksha without Dharma- Study of vedas , following right way - Artha - earning rightfully and donating. - Kaama- Experienceing creation.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Thank u. & yes i feel the same too.

Comment: Also, the retiring in the forest is vanaprastha and Not Sanyasa.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi Yes, he is to continue doing Agnihotra even after retiring, This is mentioned in the other verses.

Comment: thanks ... people often mistake vanaprastha as sanyasa !