# How can one know their dharma?

Tags: vedanta, dharma, advaita, purushartha, artha

Living one's dharma seems to be paramount, but first I must discover what my *dharma* is. I was born and reared in the West, so how can I discover my *dharma*?

I have read the Gita and it helped me understand different paths, but how can I know what is proper for me? I don't have a caste or any other similar societal role. Do I simply do something I am interested in and then it will become clear?

IOW, **how may one discover their specific *dharma*?** How should one spend their days without knowing this? Or am I missing the point and discovering one's dharma is a part of the process?

---

If it helps to know, *Advaita* appeals to me the most, but I am always open to new understandings.

Comment: You can read Bhagwat Geeta initially to get some clue.

Comment: ask your elders (parents), or church priest. god doesn't forsake anyone who surrenders to him.

Comment: You can check my answer [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18679). Hinduism does not encourage renunciation without fulfilling the primary duties first. BTW, your Q has been edited immensely , so not quite sure whether the present Q is the Q u were asking in the original version

Comment: @ram My elders emphasize *artha*. They believe that it is more important for me to make money, even if the job is unethical or causes emotio-psychological suffering to myself or others. I have the mind for graduate school, but it requires a lot of debt. I don't like the idea of anyone being indebted to anyone else. So, I'm not certain how to move forward in life. I've thought about becoming an itinerant nun, trading knowledge for *bhiksha*. I've also contemplated and even attempted to become a hermit. However, I must take medicine, so I cannot see how these options are viable.

Comment: @Rohit. I am currently re-reading the Geeta.

Comment: @RubelliteFae The greatest Dharma is Atma Dharma. Know thyself. Knowing ourselves is our real Dharma all dharmas are secondary. I recommend you to read teachings of Ramana Maharshi, Nisargadatta Maharaja or Jiddu KRISHNAMURTI. You will know your Dharma. Don't read Geeta anymore if already didn't work.

Comment: "I am more interested in learning how to discover my dharma and (perhaps thereby) my artha” this. Artha should always conform to dharma. You don't have to become a renunciate or a hermit. Dharmic fulfillment of desires is allowed bin Hinduism. It is one of the four attainables. Now to your specific circumstance, can you postpone grad studies by a couple of years during which you can earn/save some? What kind of Jobs do you hope to get after grad? Will the income justify the debt? What is the worst if u don't go to grad school? And so on. Good wishes

Comment: As a follow up, I decided to return to Uni to pursue a degree in physics. I know that I am predisposed to loving learning, discovery, and knowledge, so perhaps that gives me some idea, but I still am rather lost as to what I "should be" doing in accordance with my dharma. Also, if it helps, Advaita Vedanta appeals the most to me. I can see the truth is other wisdoms, but they all ultimately come back to a non-dual oneness (for me).

Comment: see https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10876/how-do-we-decide-what-is-dharma-and-adharma?rq=1 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purushartha and also purushartha/goal/duty as per his ashrama is given at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashrama_(stage)#Ashrama_and_Purushartha

Comment: @Rickross Thanks for your comment. My initial question was too highly specific to me as personal advice and contained way more than it needed. This made the question I was trying to ask difficult to understand. Pradip's quotation of Swami Tapasyananda is intuitive and is how I decided to proceed since the question had been long unanswered. Hopefully others can gain as much hope and faith from this Q&A as I have.

Comment: Vivekachoodamani
59. Without knowing the supreme Reality, the study of the Sastras is futile. Having known the supreme Reality, the study of the Sastras is again futile.

Comment: Very relevant link: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2392/how-can-one-know-which-path-among-karma-bhakti-and-jnana-is-suitable-for-him

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible answer based on this Gita verse is given below.

> One's own duty, even if without excellence, is more meritorious
>   spiritually than the apparently well-performed duty of another. For,
>   no sin is incurred by one doing works ordained according to one's
>   nature.

Gita 18.47

This verse was interpreted by old commentators as jobs ascribed to particular castes. This verse is interpreted differently by those who follow Vivekananda's psychological explanation of Varna.

> These verses, which were easy for our ancients to understand, pose
>   great difficulty for us today. So long as Varna was identified with
>   the endogamous caste, and valid texts ascribed particular works to
>   each caste it was easy to find out one's Svadharma, and if one had a
>   will, to perform it too. That a priest's son should be a priest, a
>   soldier's son a soldier, a merchant's son a merchant, an
>   agriculturist's son an agriculturist, a serf's son a serf - is an
>   arrangement that could be practised to some extent in the old feudal
>   society when educational opportunities were restricted, when there was
>   no choice in following professions, when social contacts were limited,
>   and when the validity of the system was accepted by the people in
>   general. But today such an idea of Svadharma hereditarily determined,
>   is impossible of practice. Society and professions have become
>   competitive. The imparting of education without any restriction
>   imposed by caste, has helped the shuffling of professional abilities
>   among all members of society, setting aside hereditary factors. So it
>   has become honourable for any one to follow any profession, and the
>   determination of Svadharma based on birth as in a caste based economy,
>   has become impractical and impossible, and also undesirable. In a
>   democratic society, the same kind of education is open to all, and
>   every one is eligible, according to one's qualification and capacity,
>   to positions of power, prestige and high income. In these days of
>   national armies every able-bodied citizen has the eligibility to be
>   recruited - he may even be conscripted - in the armed forces of the
>   country. In such a milieu, if the Gita idea of Svadharma is accepted
>   as caste based, as it was understood a few generations back, and as it
>   used to be interpreted by old commentators, then it has become
>   thoroughly outmoded and will be rejected by every section of society
>   in India and outside.
>
> But as already pointed out, **the wording of the Gita about Caturvarnya,
>   except as interpreted by old commentators, does not mean endogamous
>   castes, but the four psychological types**. If this is accepted,
>   Svadharma would mean only work that springs out of one's own nature
>   and therefore adapted to one's natural development. **But how to
>   recognise these types and how to provide them with work suited to
>   their nature - is a problem that cannot be solved. We have to leave
>   work based on psychological type as an ideal arrangement in a more
>   rationally organised society of the future.** There is no other way
>   today but to understand Svadharma as the duty devolving on oneself in
>   society, inclusive of the profession one follows. If that is done well
>   with God in view, and not merely for remuneration or with a worldly
>   master in view, then one may be said to follow Svadharma.

Commentary on Gita 18.47 by Swami Tapasyananda in his English translation of Srimad Bhagavad Gita.

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much!  "Svadharma would (be) adapted to one's natural development." This was my intuition, but I wanted to be certain I wasn't following my ego desires. Sometimes it is difficult to discern ignorant craving from natural need. I'm also glad to hear I needn't be overly concerned with payment, because in past money has made ego distractions easier and my personal development slower. Since asking the question I have returned to Uni to study physics & philosophy.  I'm particularly drawn to the Gita's sections on Jñāna yoga and am elated to hear I can pursue what I most enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

The only very practical advice is to do your "naadi reading". I mean "Agastya naadi astrology".  I did last year "Kotchara Shanthi" and reached "Maha Siva  Vakkiyam", what remedies I will do this year. It is not about finding out your past and future. It is about changing it. Pictures - my remedies, abisheka to Agastya and Lopamudra.

[image: My remedies].
[image: Abisheka to Agastya and Lopamudra].

[Naadi Astrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadi_astrology)

Comment: "an offering of Rs. 30008, Rs. 21008" - is this the fees you charge or you paid someone else?

Comment: Cool question. It is not an advertisement. Guru dhaan is charity. It differs according to the person and chapter. Can be less or more.  Are you going to do the remedies as shown and to what extent, including Guru dhaan is up to you. Reading fees are separate.

Comment: I don't think these "remedies" have any effect. From what I heard all these "naadi" astrologers have prior arrangements with the hotel staff where the "clients" stay to share details about clients' background/history/family details. That is how they gain trust of clients and then go on to "predict" the future. Figures like 21008, 30008, etc don't sound like charity. It's extortion from gullible people.