# How should be an ideal husband and wife according to our scriptures?

Tags: scripture, marriage, grihastha, wife

What are the qualities a ideal husband and wife must possess?
How should they lead an ideal married life?

Comment: Have you read the Ramayana? Ram and Sita are the ideal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the significance of Marriage as per Sanatana dharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18013/what-is-the-significance-of-marriage-as-per-sanatana-dharma)